# Trouble looping through the inputs and adding them

Tags: javascript

Having an issue with `peoplePaid()` looping through all the inputs with the `.persons` class on a page through an add button. I believe this issue is that `#paidTotal` is trying to add contents from an array in `.persons` but can't access them (gives me an undefined error in console).

This variable works but only if there's one `.persons` class with a variable...

```
var personsCheck = parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName('persons')[0].value);
```

However I need it to dynamically loop the values of the array that is created through `.persons` elements. What am I missing?

```js
function peoplePaid() {
  var checkTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('check').value);
  var personsCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('persons');
  var paidTotal = document.getElementById('paidTotal');

  for (var i = 1; i < personsCheck.length; i += 1) {
    paidTotal += personsCheck[i];
  }
  paidTotal.innerHTML = checkTotal - personsCheck;
}
```

```html
$ <input type="text" id="check" value="" />

<h3>Number of People: <span id="numberOfPeople"></span></h3>

<div>
  <div id="userNumbers">
    <input type="text" class="persons" name="person">
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="peoplePaid()">Calculate</button>
<!--Paid Amount-->
<div>
  <h3>Paid Amount: <span id="paidTotal"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paidTotal` is an element. I believe you do not want to use `+=` on the element itself. You should add the total to a variable.

Also, as the index of collections are 0 based, you have to start the value of `i` from `0`. You have to take the `value` property from each element.

**Please Note:** It is good practice to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML` when dealing with text only content.

Try the following way:

```js
function peoplePaid() {
  var checkTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('check').value);
  var personsCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('persons');
  var paidTotal = document.getElementById('paidTotal');
  var pCheck = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < personsCheck.length; i += 1) {
    pCheck += personsCheck[i].value;
  }
  paidTotal.textContent = checkTotal - pCheck;
}
```

```html
$ <input type="text" id="check" value="" />

<h3>Number of People: <span id="numberOfPeople"></span></h3>

<div>
  <div id="userNumbers">
    <input type="text" class="persons" name="person">
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="peoplePaid()">Calculate</button>
<!--Paid Amount-->
<div>
  <h3>Paid Amount: <span id="paidTotal"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some mistakes exists in your code:

1. `paidTotal` is an element but in `paidTotal += personsCheck[i];` you have used it some a numeric variable.
2. in your loop, index must starts from zero not one.
3. in this line: `paidTotal += personsCheck[i];` you have added `personsCheck[i]` element to `paidTotal` instead of its value.

the corrected code is like this:

```js
function peoplePaid() {
  var checkTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('check').value);
  var personsCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('persons');
  var paidTotal = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < personsCheck.length; i += 1) {
    paidTotal += personsCheck[i].value * 1;
  }
  document.getElementById('paidTotal').innerHTML = checkTotal - paidTotal;
}
```

```html
$ <input type="text" id="check" value="" />

<h3>Number of People: <span id="numberOfPeople"></span></h3>

<div>
  <div id="userNumbers">
    <input type="text" class="persons" name="person">
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="peoplePaid()">Calculate</button>
<!--Paid Amount-->
<div>
  <h3>Paid Amount: <span id="paidTotal"></span></h3>
</div>
```